# Stop TableView / TableViewCell animation (probably on willdisplaycell)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I've noticed this with a couple of UITableView's that I have coded, and that is when there is a lengthy list, or if I animate the displaying of the table itself, the cells have an animation, like the table is constructing the cells as I'm scrolling down.

The animation looks like the accessory view sliding from the left to the right, and I have a top-right label that does the same. 
On another table that I slide in from the bottom, it looks like the buttons and text from the table expand as the table does.

How do I stop this?

I am using Swift, but if you know the answer in OBJ-C that would be okay too.

Also, if you need a preview, check this: 
[image: gif of what the animation looks like]

I've tried searching for this and I only get posts about making an animation within the table cells not removing this one!

Comment: Thanks Mangesh, I couldn't post an inline image yet :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out how to stop it! It was because of the accessory view and making sure the cells have performed the `layoutIfNeeded`.

First, I removed the `accessoryview` from StoryBoard and in `willDisplayCell:` I used this:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { () -> Void in
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()      
}
```

As well as:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { () -> Void in
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`